# Determining various scenarios in string array using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I am loading a file that contains a CSV and I'm using LINQ to determine if there any failures and I have fallen at the first hurdle:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Projects\Misc Files\FontToImageGenerator\test\testMODIFIED.txt");
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    var splitup = line.Split(',');
    //Check first 3 are from A-q or 65-113 in ASCII
    var first3ok = splitup.Take(3).All(x => Char.GetNumericValue((char)x[0]) >= 65 && <= 113); //****This doesn't compile**** IEnumberable<string> does not contain a defintition for All and the best overload arguments contains invalid arguemnts

    //Check next 20 chars and they alternate matching A-q and 1-9


    //Check the next char is from A-I


   //Last 8 chars in the line should contain 2 chars uppercase from A-Z
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using a regex, by the way?

Comment: Thought that converting a char to int was more readable! Added the compiler error

Comment: If Uncle Bob to see this, he'd not be satisfied with the readability of your code ...it would have been much better with a regex :)

Comment: Uncle Bob can recommend me a RegEx then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current error really doesn't have anything to do with LINQ. You'll see the same thing if you do:

```
string x = ...;

if (Char.GetNumericValue((char)x[0]) >= 65 && <= 113)
```

That's just not valid C# - you haven't got a valid operand for the `<=` part. You'd need something like:

```
if (Char.GetNumericValue((char)x[0]) >= 65 && 
    Char.GetNumericValue((char)x[0]) <= 113)
```

I don't think that's *really* what you mean though - I think you've misunderstood what `GetNumericValue` does. I suspect you really want:

```
x[0] >= 'A' && x[0] <= 'q'
```

So:

```
var first3ok = splitup.Take(3).All(x => x[0] >= 'A' && x[0] <= 'q');
```

Note that this isn't checking the first three *characters* - it's checking the first character of each of the first three *bits* of the comma-separated string. It's unclear whether that's what you meant or not.

However, it looks to me like this is one situation where you'd be better off using a regex...

Comment: The first 3 bits will be singular so its ok. How would you use Regex in this scenario?

Comment: @Jon: It's unclear, as you haven't really described the format - whether it's the same for each bit, or varies by bit etc.

Comment: Each CSV bit will contain a single character and needs to be from A-q

Comment: How about this: Regex f = new Regex("^[A-Za-q]$");
                var first3okd = splitup.Take(3).All(x => f.IsMatch(x));

Comment: @Jon: Yup, that looks like it would probably be fine. Note that that excludes the square brackets, backslash etc which occur between Z and a. I don't know if you want to include those or not. Given your previous questions, I suspect you may want them...

Comment: Shite, glad you're on the ball thats why I originally tried to 65-113 as integers

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess change

```
var first3ok = splitup.Take(3).All(x => Char.GetNumericValue((char)x[0]) >= 65 && <= 113);
```

to

```
var first3ok = splitup.Take(3).All(x => Char.GetNumericValue((char)x[0]) >= 65 && Char.GetNumericValue((char)x[0]) <= 113);
```

You can't do `x (>=5 && <= 7)`, it has to be `(x>=5) && (x<=7)`

Comment: Yippie, just beat Mr Skeet! (with an inferior answer).